# rbind in a list in r (text to column)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation, tidy

I have 3 `.csv` files in one directory. The data sets have headers and `text; text; text;` format.

```
`list_data <- list("Red; Green", 
                  "Green; Blue",
                  "Blue; Yellow")
print(list_data)`
```

and I would like to merge them into 1 .csv based on the same headers.

```
  files  <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv')
tables <- lapply(files, read.csv, header = TRUE)
combined.df <- do.call(rbind , tables)
str(combined.df)
```

How to get around this? many thanks in advance.

Comment: Blindly assigning headers over existing files can be hazardous if you are not certain that the columns are otherwise the same structure. If the headers are different, how certain are you that the columns are still the same? Request: the sample data here (`list_data`) is not a great representation of CSV formats, can you provide a few lines from 2-3 CSV files for demonstration?

Comment: looking at it carefully, I find out the third data set has additional columns. Trying to subset the list based on the common columns.

Comment: If I'm reading your code right, you're using `read.csv` which uses `sep=","`; your `list_data` values look to be `;`-delimited (`read.csv2`?), and are either no-headers or headers-only. However, if those are representative of the headers you want, then I suggest using `dplyr::bind_rows(tables)` or `data.table::rbindlist(tables, fill=TRUE, use.names=TRUE)`, both will align by-name as I think you intend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions about the real data, I'll change the sample data slightly:

```r
list_data <- list(file1="Red; Green\n1;2", file2="Green; Blue\n3;4", file3="Blue; Yellow\n5;6")
```

I added names to enable the option to preserve file name in the rows of data (far below).

```r
# tables <- lapply(setNames(nm = files), read.csv2) # what you call with a file list
tables <- lapply(list_data, function(z) read.csv2(text = z))
str(tables)
# List of 3
#  $ file1:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ Red  : int 1
#   ..$ Green: int 2
#  $ file2:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ Green: int 3
#   ..$ Blue : int 4
#  $ file3:'data.frame':    1 obs. of  2 variables:
#   ..$ Blue  : int 5
#   ..$ Yellow: int 6
dplyr::bind_rows(tables)
#   Red Green Blue Yellow
# 1   1     2   NA     NA
# 2  NA     3    4     NA
# 3  NA    NA    5      6
data.table::rbindlist(tables, fill = TRUE, use.name = TRUE)
#      Red Green  Blue Yellow
#    <int> <int> <int>  <int>
# 1:     1     2    NA     NA
# 2:    NA     3     4     NA
# 3:    NA    NA     5      6
```

If you want to preserve the file name with each row, then

```r
dplyr::bind_rows(tables, .id = "filename")
#   filename Red Green Blue Yellow
# 1    file1   1     2   NA     NA
# 2    file2  NA     3    4     NA
# 3    file3  NA    NA    5      6
data.table::rbindlist(tables, fill = TRUE, use.name = TRUE, idcol = "filename")
#    filename   Red Green  Blue Yellow
#      <char> <int> <int> <int>  <int>
# 1:    file1     1     2    NA     NA
# 2:    file2    NA     3     4     NA
# 3:    file3    NA    NA     5      6
```